# inner join y left join en Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Asumiendo que tenemos la siguiente estructura de tablas en una base de datos

**TABLA USERS**

```
MariaDB [blog]> describe users;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| idUser       | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| nameUser     | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
| passwordUser | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| statusUser   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at   | datetime     | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Posterior la siguiente estructura

**TABLA CATEGORIES**

```
MariaDB [blog]> describe categories;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| idCategory          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| nameCategory        | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
| descriptionCategory | mediumtext   | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| statusCategory      | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| user_id             | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| created_at          | datetime     | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Haciendo una consulta con `INNER JOIN` o `JOIN` en mariaDB deberíamos obtener todos los registros que tienen vinculo o relación entre ambas tablas; en otras palabras todos los usuarios que a su vez tienen registrada al menos una categoria dada de alta; del modo siguiente

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT users.nameUser, categories.nameCategory
    -> FROM users
    -> JOIN categories
    -> ON users.idUser = categories.user_id;
+----------+---------------+
| nameUser | nameCategory  |
+----------+---------------+
| alfa     | backend       |
| beta     | frontend      |
| gama     | servers       |
| delta    | mantenimiento |
+----------+---------------+
```

Por ejemplo para ahora obtener el listado total de usuarios incluyendo aquellos que no tienen asociada el alta de ninguna categoria, usamos un `LEFT JOIN` del modo siguiente

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT users.nameUser, categories.nameCategory
    -> FROM users
    -> LEFT JOIN categories
    -> ON users.idUser = categories.user_id;
+----------+---------------+
| nameUser | nameCategory  |
+----------+---------------+
| alfa     | backend       |
| beta     | frontend      |
| gama     | servers       |
| delta    | mantenimiento |
| master   | NULL          |
+----------+---------------+
```

> ¿Cómo pasar estas dos consultas al ORM Eloquent sin utilizar
>   necesariamente el queryBuilder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Asumiendo que en nuestro escenario tenemos el modelo de la tabla users llamado `User`, a través del encadenamiento de métodos podemos hacer lo siguiente valiendonos de `select()` y de `join()` ambos métodos en **Eloquent**

> En la construcción de la consulta, a la variable `$data` la igualamos
>   a la clase del Modelo `User` y este a su vez accede al método estático
>   `select()`

**INNER JOIN**

```
$data = User::select('users.nameUser', 'categories.nameCategory')
                ->join('categories', 'users.idUser', '=', 'categories.user_id')
                ->get();

        return $data;
```

**Lo anterior me da a devolver la siguiente información**

```
[
{
"nameUser": "alfa",
"nameCategory": "backend"
},
{
"nameUser": "beta",
"nameCategory": "frontend"
},
{
"nameUser": "gama",
"nameCategory": "servers"
},
{
"nameUser": "delta",
"nameCategory": "mantenimiento"
}
]
```

**LEFT JOIN**

```
$data = User::select('users.nameUser', 'categories.nameCategory')
                ->leftjoin('categories', 'users.idUser', '=', 'categories.user_id')
                ->get();

        return $data;
```

**Lo anterior me da a devolver la siguiente información**

```
[
{
"nameUser": "alfa",
"nameCategory": "backend"
},
{
"nameUser": "beta",
"nameCategory": "frontend"
},
{
"nameUser": "gama",
"nameCategory": "servers"
},
{
"nameUser": "delta",
"nameCategory": "mantenimiento"
},
{
"nameUser": "master",
"nameCategory": null
}
]
```

Comment: A que te refieres cuando dices encadenamiento de metodos.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz entiendo que se refiere al Patron Builder, el que te permite ir invocando metodos con "->", y se va "construyendo" el objeto.